# Dogs are the best pet/pets?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, adverbs, singular-vs-plural, spoken-english

I always think that ***the best*** must be followed by a singular noun as follows:

> Dogs are the best pet.

---

However, I found this while reading:

> Dogs are the best pets.

---

Is this grammatically correct?

Comment: It's correct and more logical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think generally, the noun following **the best** should match the plural/singular sense of the word it is describing:

It may be true that *usually* you describe a single thing as being the best. But, **the best** can also refer to the an upper tier of good-ness, rather than the single best version of something:

[This article](https://www.foxbusiness.com/personal-finance/best-worst-us-states-start-business) has both senses:

> These[plural] *are* the best and worst US **states** to start a business
>
> Texas[singular] *was* ranked the best **state** overall to start a business, according to the study.

You can find other examples by searching ["are the best"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are+the+best%22&rlz=1C1NDCM_jaJP718JP719&ei=W0klXa3BJoby8QXE6Y6QDg&start=10&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwjt2umUo6njAhUGebwKHcS0A-IQ8NMDCL0B&cshid=1562724950341988&biw=1920&bih=958) and ["is the best"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22is+the+best%22&rlz=1C1NDCM_jaJP718JP719&oq=%22is+the+best%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l5.12363j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and comparing the results. The first will usually have a plural noun following **best**, while the second will have a singular noun following **best**.

---

So, you have two options, either using "a dog" in the singular sense and say:

> A dog is the best pet.

**or** stick with the phrase you found while reading:

> Dogs are the best pets.